# Best practice to call a function from a button-link?

Tags: functions, links, buttons

I am developing a WordPress website where I have to link a button to a function inside the functions.php file. Meaning that when someone clicks on a certain button, this will trigger a call to a specific function.

I have read about various ways to approach this:

By creating a link acting as a button:

`<a href="?action=linked_function" class="button btn btn-primary">Click to call function</a>`

Or a form submission:

```
<form action="functions.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Call function" />
</form>
```

Others suggest using ajax for this case, although I don't really care if the page has to reload after the function call or if I have to redirect the user to the previous page.

I am wondering though what are the best and most importantly safest options to develop this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the function? It's an important detail.

Comment: @JacobPeattie A custom function I created in the functions.php file.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What does it _do_?

Comment: What I think for you: it's you can create your button with the HTML button tag and do a POST or GET call with JS when a user click on the button.... In your functions.php, init the function only if $_POST['value'] or $_GET['value'] is isset and equal to your value.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It’s a function that makes a call to the Stripe API.

Comment: @Sam Ok, so you mean like an onclick or onsubmit event? So if I use post for example then I have to submit a form (verify with wp_nonce) while the action of the form would be functions.php and based on the value I will trigger the function I need.